# How to compare column names from entity framework to content of class fields?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have list of objects (`List<Seat> CurrentSeatStates`). Those objects contain filed named Number. And content of those `Number` fields is the same as some column names. I am using entity framework. Here is part of my code:

```
Seats seatsRow = new Seats();

seatsRow = (from seats in Db.Seats where seats.SeanceId == seanceId select seats).First();              

seatsRow.A1 = !(from s in CurrentSeatStates where s.Number.Equals("A1") select s.IsEnabled).Single();
seatsRow.A2 = !(from s in CurrentSeatStates where s.Number.Equals("A2") select s.IsEnabled).Single();
seatsRow.A3 = !(from s in CurrentSeatStates where s.Number.Equals("A3") select s.IsEnabled).Single();
...
```

I would like to **use foreach loop here and dynamically compare column name** (example seatsRow.**A3**) **and content of field `Number`**. So that I would not have to use hardcoded column name. And if those two equals (column name and content of Number filed) them set value from another field `IsEnabled`.

Any help here much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
PropertyInfo pi = seatsRow.GetType().GetProperty(*columnName*);
            pi.SetValue(seatsRow, *value*, null);
```

Where under *columnName* you can set changeable column name and under *value* you set value that you want to set.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Type` method `GetProperties()` then using reflection you can set properties with value from queries.